# Deducing properties of the $\ell_3$ norm from the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have a function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) \geq 0$ normalised so that $\|f\|_1 = 1$, where
$$
\| f\|_p = \left( \int_0^1 f(x)^p d x \right)^{1/p}.
$$
Moreover, we know that $\| f \|_2 = A$. Is it possible to bound $\| f \|_3$ in terms of $A$? What about if we know, in addition, $f$ is bounded as $f \leq B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$. Now, $||f||_3=\infty$, but $$||f||_1=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\ dx=\frac{3}{2}, $$$$||f||_2^2=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{2/3}}\ dx=3.$$ That is above integrals are finite, normalise $f$ by multiplying $2/3$. So, first problem has negative answer.

Now, for the second problem has affirmative answer. Note that $$\int_0^1|f|^3=\int_0^1|f|^2|f|\leq \min\bigg\{B^2\int_0^1|f|,\ B\int_0^1|f|^2\bigg\}<\infty$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does it change if we know $\|f\|_3$ and want to found $\|f\|_2$?

Comment: **What is Interpolation?** In simple terms, if a linear function is continuous on a certain space $L_p$ and also on a certain space $L_q$, then it is also continuous on the space $L_r$, for any intermediate $r$ between $p$ and $q$. In other words, $L_r$ is a space that is intermediate between $L_p$ and $L_q$.

Comment: Is there a theorem which bounds the r norm with the p and q norm?

Comment: In other words, $0<p<q<r\leq \infty$ we have $$||f||_q\leq ||f||_p^\lambda\cdot ||f||^{1-\lambda}_r,$$ where $q^{-1}=\lambda p^{-1}+(1-\lambda)r^{-1}.$ You can find a proof in Folland Real analysis, see proposition 6.10 on page 185, Chapter 6.

Comment: Otherwise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#:~:text=In%20simple%20terms%2C%20if%20a,Lp%20and%20Lq.